# why f_rename of fatfs is very slow?

Tags: stm32, sd, dma, fat

I'am developing a datalogger with an stm32L496 + FreeRtos + FatFs. The data logger save data to a buffer and when is full, the buffer is saved in a file on an SDcard with the help of fatfs and the SDMMC+DMA.
When the working file is too big (15Mo), this file is moved to another directory. But sometimes, I have overrun because of the very long time of f_rename (500ms). I can increase the buffer to hide the issue but I don't understand why this function takes so much time.

Anybody has this issue?
I'm using Fatfs R0.12c with FAT32 format.

I have found that the code takes a long time when the function call "follow_path", when checking if the new file exist and when it call "dir_find" with the variable "path" empty. (So when this is the last segment).

In f_rename :

```
/* At FAT12/FAT16/FAT32 */
mem_cpy(buf, djo.dir + DIR_Attr, 21);   
mem_cpy(&djn, &djo, sizeof (DIR));      
res = follow_path(&djn, path_new); // the problematic function  
if (res == FR_OK) {                     
  res = (djn.obj.sclust == djo.obj.sclust && djn.dptr == djo.dptr) ?
     FR_NO_FILE : FR_EXIST;
}
```

And in follow_path:

```
for (;;) {
  res = create_name(dp, &path);  // if after this function, path == ""
  if (res != FR_OK) break;
  res = dir_find(dp); // this function can takes 500ms even @ 50Mhz
  ns = dp->fn[NSFLAG];
```

The code isn't faster if I increase the clock speed so I think this is a software issue.

Any idea ?

[EDIT]
Ok, I tried in exFat and I have the same issue but inconsistently. It happened maybe every 20 or 30 rename.

I found here https://github.com/greiman/SdFat/issues/250 that the SDMMC of STM32 could be the problem. The guy says :

> The SDMMC controller causes the SD to need to copy data from partial
> filled flash pages so there are occasional writes with many
> milliseconds of latency

I someone can try the rename function with an stm32 or another microcontroler to measure the latency, it would be a big help.

Comment: well, the problem is clearly in `dir_find` then,  have you profiled that? And the code *not* getting faster with higher CPU speed indicates a hardware issue, not a software issue.

Comment: actually, this is this the sdmmc frequency not cpu. Dir_find loop on all files and break as nothing have an empty name...

Comment: great. So, you know now where the time is spent. What's the question, then?

Comment: Why is so long, is it normal? It's insane as it's faster to copy manually all the file and remove the old one.